# Pinning Metro Apps To Taskbar Windows 10 Powershell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

The following code will pin a metro app to start given an AUMID

If you change

```
-match 'Pin To Start'
```

Unfortunately changing the match to 'Pin To Taskbar' does not work. What is going on here?

```
function Pin-Taskbar {    param(
        [string]$aumid,
        [switch]$unpin
    )
    try{
        if ($unpin.IsPresent){
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Path -eq $aumid}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from Taskbar'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$aumid' unpinned from Taskbar"
        }else{
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Path -eq $aumid}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Pin to Taskbar'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$aumid' pinned to Taskbar"
        }
    }catch{
        Write-Error "Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?)"
    }
}


Pin-Taskbar king.com.CandyCrushSaga_kgqvnymyfvs32!App
```

Comment: You're not *supposed* to be able to programmatically tell the user that your app is important to them. ["Why is there no programmatic access to the Start menu pin list?" - The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler there must be a way

Comment: "Note  Applications cannot programmatically pin themselves to the taskbar. That functionality is reserved strictly for the user." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391692%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: See also: [How to pin an application to the taskbar `[closed]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159451/how-to-pin-an-application-to-the-taskbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are a good citizen and do not want to spam the taskbar of the users.

In previous versions of Windows, you were able to use the verb `Pintotaskbar` to programmatically un-/pin programs to your taskbar.

```
$shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application" 
$folder = $shell.Namespace((Join-Path $env:SystemRoot System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0))
$item = $folder.Parsename('powershell_ise.exe')
$item.invokeverb('taskbarpin');
```

This no longer works in Windows 10. The verb `Pintotaskbar` simply is not <strike>exist</strike> accessible anymore.

Hence, an unapproved 3rd-party command prompt utility
called [SysPin](http://www.technosys.net/products/utils/pintotaskbar) was brought to life - that allows you to do exactly what you want (though it does not work with each and every app, especially UWP/Metro apps).

However, since Windows 10 version 1607 there is a new official way: adding a <[TaskbarLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar)>
See: [Customize Pinned Items on Taskbar in Windows 10 1607 during OSD with ConfigMgr](http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2016/08/03/customize-pinned-items-on-taskbar-in-windows-10-1607-during-osd-with-configmgr/)

Comment: I am not trying to spam a taskbar to users. As you said the verb doesn't exist anymore in Win 10 . What stinks is I am only interested in Win 10 and Metro apps. SysPin wont pin Metro apps. Is there any other approach you can think of for metro apps in Win 10?

Comment: This is not actually true. The verb very much still exists. It's just not available for everyone.