# ClickOnce create new shortcuts (suffix -1, -2) after application upgrade

Tags: clickonce, shortcut

I have a WPF app, which gets deployed via ClickOnce.
ClickOnce create new shortcuts (suffix -1, -2) after every application upgrade. This leads to multiple shortcut on my desktop.

Also, if I pin the app to my taskbar in win10, it removes it after every application upgrade, which requires repining the app.

How can I stop both of the issues?

1. Stop multiple shortcut in desktop
2. Stop removing the pinned app from taskbar

Answer (score 0):

> Stop multiple shortcut in desktop

You can handle this in code:

1. first disable auto create shortcut
2. check and create new shortcut on first run.

[image]

```
static void CheckForShortcut()
{
    if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
        if (ad.IsFirstRun)  //first time user has run the app
            {
                Assembly code = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                string company = string.Empty;
                string description = string.Empty;
                if (Attribute.IsDefined(code, typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute)))
                {
                AssemblyCompanyAttribute ascompany =
                  (AssemblyCompanyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(code,
                  typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute));
               company = ascompany.Company;
            }
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(code, typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)))
            {
                AssemblyDescriptionAttribute asdescription =
                  (AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(code,
                    typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute));
                description = asdescription.Description;
            }
            if (company != string.Empty && description != string.Empty)
            {
                string desktopPath = string.Empty;
                desktopPath =
                  string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                    "\\", description, ".appref-ms");
                string shortcutName = string.Empty;
                shortcutName =
                  string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs),
                    "\\", company, "\\", description, ".appref-ms");
                   System.IO.File.Copy(shortcutName, desktopPath,true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Stop removing the pinned app from taskbar

check this: [How to pin an application to the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159451/how-to-pin-an-application-to-the-taskbar)