# How do I make the WPF application pinned to the taskbar after the first launch?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I need help. I made a WPF application. Its functionality is that it launches the application when it is launched. But if it is pinned to the taskbar, then a JumpList appears. From which you can also call other applications. I ran into this problem: I do not know how to make the program automatically pinned to the taskbar after the first launch. Please help someone. I read on microsoft's website, but it's not suitable for wpf. Please help with this.

Maybe there is some kind of library? Maybe there is a way with the registry?

Comment: You can't. Only the end-user can pin programs to the start menu or taskbar, because we can't trust narcissitic software publishers to not spam their icons everywhere.

Comment: @Dai And if you make a dialog box that would fix?

Comment: What do dialog-boxes have to do with anything?

Comment: @Dai Nothing, but surely there is no library for pinning?

Comment: No, because Microsoft doesn't want you to: only the end-user is supposed to be able to pin/unpin to the taskbar and start-menu. The only exceptions are OEMs who can configure up to 3 (IIRC) programs as part of their factory image, and system administrators via group policy. While it's true that some third-parties have figured-out how to pin themselves via undocumented APIs and/or registry-keys, you won't hear me tell you how they did it because I want your software to be _good software citizens_ that respects the end-user.

Comment: @Dai But you could just show how it is done and works. What is there such a thing as why they refuse it? I will not use it, but I want to see what it is possible to do.

Comment: I can't, because I honestly don't know how it's done either - I never really looked into it.

Comment: Calling an external program can use the Process.Start() method. Your requirement is to start the WPF project and fix the program in the taskbar?

Comment: @Lynn-MSFT The program uses Process.Start(). I need the program to be already fixed in the taskbar after the first launch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask for support for pinning, here is why.

Microsoft goes in great length to prevent applications altering user preferences. Why? Because otherwise, every application would do it. Giving access to user preferences via API means developers start exploiting it. It means applications fighting for screen space. You install compnay A product and it unpins company B product.

If such API existed, that is malware.

And an API for only the calling executable is not viable, it would mean that somewhere deep in the operating system the function call to do it for any executable exists. And then somebody finds it and calls it directly. Besides, it has been a big trouble for Microsoft to decouple the shell as it is.

Instead, explorer handles it.

Further reading [Why is there no programmatic access to the Start menu pin list?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=42673).

---

Some application do manage to pin.
Regardless of what, it is a bad practice.
It is not guaranteed to work, much less in the next Windows update.

One way is to mimic user input. It is hard to consider all cases (what if the taskbar is hidden, what if it is not in the usual place, what if explorer is not running, etc.), but you can imagine setting the pointer position and sending keys.

Another way would be to write directly to the list.  You might have found out that the pinned items are at:

%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
And they are regular, good old, shortcuts. And you could add your own. And it would not work.

---

Thus, the answer is "Please don't do it".

For a more detailed explanation, you can try to refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57160775/17722391).